# Rails - Cannot find controller_action_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Hey guys i probably have a simple problem which annoys me for 2 hours now.

I try to set up a **menu_item_icon** which is linked to one of my controller actions.

So far every of these **menu_items** work. But there is one where I always get the failure message '**Controller_Action path not found**' and I am wondering why this is happening.

Here are some code-snippets from

- a) The definition of the **controller_action** itself
- b) The **route** in the **routes.rb**
- c) The **menu_item_icon** link on some of my views

**a) Definition of action in controller sells_controller.rb**

```
def manage_sell
  @stored_sells = SaveSell.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html{render 'manage_sells',:layout=>false}
  end
end
```

**b) The route for action manage_sell in my routes.rb**

```
resources :sells, :only=>[:show,:new,:create] do
  [...]
  get :manage_sell, :on=>:collection
  [...]
end
```

**c) menu_item_icon link inone of my views**

```
[...]
=menu_item_icon('m_sells','Manage Sells'),sells_manage_sell_path
[...]
```

So what is going wrong?

Comment: Instead of using `sells_manage_sell_path` try using `"/sells/manage_sell"`

Comment: can you put an ouput for `rake routes` please?

Comment: The outprint of the rake routes for the row sells#manage_sell: **manage_sell_sells GET    /sells/manage_sell(.:format)            sells#manage_sell**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rake routes gives the name you have to use, so in your case you have to write `manage_sell_sells_path`.

I do have a comment regarding naming: I would prefer the simpler `manage` and then it would all make sense. If you define the route to be on a member, the path would be `manage_sell_path`.

So my guess is your route definition should be

```
resources :sells, only: [:show, :new, :create] do 
  get :manage, on: :member
end
```

as the naming now seems to imply you are "managing" a single sell.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be

```
manage_sell_sells_path
```

instead of

```
manage_sells_sell_path
```

Because your action is

```
manage_sell
```

and controller is

```
sells
```

Though there is no action named 'manage_sells' it raise no **'Controller_Action path not found'** errors

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake and i already correct that. Thanks @nathanvda